# django-cache-machine and Redis

Tags: django, django-cache, django-cache-machine

I'm trying to use django-cache-machine to cache queries within my application, but I want to use Redis as a backend. [The docs](http://jbalogh.me/projects/cache-machine/) don't really explain how to do this, yet [the repository](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine) is filled with Redis references, so I'm pretty sure it's possible. I want to make sure I do it right though, so I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with configuring this and maybe more importantly, knows if there are any caveats?

Answer (score 3):

In your settings set:

CACHE_MACHINE_USE_REDIS = True

REDIS_BACKEND = redis://127.0.0.1:6379?socket_timeout=0.1

https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine/blob/master/caching/invalidation.py#L187
https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine/blob/master/caching/invalidation.py#L213

Comment: Please note, when setting CACHE_MACHINE_USE_REDIS = True, django-cache-machine doesn't actually use Redis to cache your model objects, so you still need memcached configured. It only uses Redis to store and manipulate flush lists.

Answer (score -1):

I have a little experience in my project, a report system that generate tables from about 50 million records.

The database is **Mysql** and I could show my settings and models FYI.

settings:

```
    # cache machine
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'caching.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': [
            '127.0.0.1:11211',
        ],
        'PREFIX': 'report:',
    },
}
CACHE_COUNT_TIMEOUT = 60 * 24  # one day
CACHE_EMPTY_QUERYSETS = True
```

models:

```
class App(**CachingMixin**, models.Model):
    **objects = CachingManager()**

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64,
                            default='')
```

**Note that** cache-machine works fine for query_set.*filter* and *count*, not good for query_set.*annotate* or *aggregate*. Of course do not forget launch your memcache client first.

And when running you can see cache-machine logs in your django*.log to tell you hit or miss cache.